# How to use custom point style in plot?

Tags: r, graphics, bitmap, plot, points

I am doing a dimensional reduction experiment, where a set of faces will be places onto a X-Y plane. I want to show the real face at each point in the plot (Example: [Figure 10 at the page 476](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/venna10a/venna10a.pdf)). Can I do this in R? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: There are grid graphics functions that will let you do that. Search for the tutorials that Paul Murrell has written. I remember one that involved putting images of chess pieces on a plot.

Comment: @DWin - this one? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/vignettes/import.pdf

Comment: @thelatemail, I think you have found an updated one that is probably better than the one I remembered.

Comment: Here is one tutorial, on doing something very similar with images: http://is-r.tumblr.com/post/33700919594/flag-space-a-scatter-plot-of-raster-images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will probably need some add-on packages like `png` and `raster` to achieve this.
So first up, make sure you have the packages loaded.

```
library(png)
library(raster)
```

Now, get an image (an awesome squiggle I made in ms paint - saved as `spotimg.png`):

[image]

Load the image into R and plot it:

```
pngimg <- readPNG("spotimg.png")
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10))
rasterImage(pngimg,4.5,4.5,5,5)
```

The last 4 inputs to the `rasterImage` call give the coordinates of the image's boundary in the format `xleft, ybottom, xright, ytop`

And bingo, there's your image plotted where you specified.

[image]

Comment: if I want to *embed* EPS images, do I need the *raster* them? If not, how can I *embed* them? Thank you.